# install tag bug?

Tags: support, tags

I've been trying to kill several birds with one stone by reviewing unanswered questions with the blacklisted installation tag. This has been effective thus far.

Unfortunately while editing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347442/install-package-from-ppa-with-setup-py-file) question I discovered this error:

[image: editfail]

I thought it was a minor hiccup so I removed all the tags and put the appropriate ones back with the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, please, don't mindlessly replace the installation tag with system-installation or software-intallation, and review **all the tags!** The problem in that question is the [setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/setup) tag which is synonymized to installation. You are not removing this tag, hence the system nags at you.

Comment: Thank you. I wondered about that but I didn't see the synonym when I hovered over the tag... bug? or operator error?